# Asymptotic growth of $f(x) = 2f(x/2 + x/\ln(x))$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrences

In [this paper on the Akra–Bazzi theorem](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/akrabazzi.pdf), Tom Leighton mentions in his remark at the bottom of page 8, that a function on the positive reals satisfying $f(x) = 2f(x/2 + x/\ln(x))$ for large enough $x$ and $f(x)$ bounded for all other $x$ has the asymptotic growth $x \ln^{\Theta(1)}x$.

I have tried to prove this by induction for concrete examples of $f$ but did not get very far.

I am looking for any concrete example for such an $f$ where it is reasonably easy to show that the asymptotic growth of $f$ is superlinear. The only requirement is that $f$ fulfils $f(x) = a f(x/a + bx/\ln(x))$ (for positive $a,b$) for large enough $x$ and is bounded for all other $x$.

I tried something like $f(x) = 1$ for $x \le 10$ and $f(x) = 2f(x/2 + x/\log_2 x)$ otherwise, which seems to get larger than $x \log_2 x$ very quickly, but the induction to prove it got very messy very fast and I gave up.

Comment: Two-sided estimates $c x \log^B x \leqslant f(x)\leqslant C x \log^A x$ for fixed constants $B<2/\log 2<A$ and appropriate constants $c,C$ are easily proved by induction.